# Are there commonly used delegates available in the standard class libraries?

Tags: c#, delegates

I find myself quite often writing delegates that take common arguments or return types. As such I often find myself using delegates like this:

```
public delegate void CommonVoidEmptyDelegate();
public delegate void CommonVoidDelegate<TParam>(TParam p);
public delegate void CommonVoidParamDelegate<TParam>(params TParam[] p);
public delegate TReturn CommonEmptyDelegate<TReturn, TParam>(TParam p);
public delegate TReturn CommonParamDelegate<TReturn, TParam>(params TParam[] p);
```

Instead of me defining these in each project I would like to know if there's something common in the framework that I can use.

Comment: you mean like `Func` and `Action` delegates?

Comment: Thanks guys for all your answers so quickly. I been avoiding pushing out .NET 3.5 to > 1,000 WM5 Devices as logistically it can be a troublesome exercise. I didn't know these delegates were available but will be very handy for use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `Action` and `Func` families of delegates.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I am still supporting .NET 2.0 so will require upgrading to 3.5. With > 1,000 PPC WM5 devices it's something I have avoided pushing out over the years.

Answer (score 3):

Converting comment to answer:

just use `Func` and `Action` delegates. They provide a great deal of flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the first two, and [`Func<T, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the third one.
There is no standard delegate for the 3rd and 5th delegates.

Comment: But you can make those and likely even call them `Func` and `Action`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth exactly, you can write your own and use the same naming convention.

Comment: Not nitpicking, I +1'd, just saying that the OP could make the missing delegates and even put them in the `System` namespace for easy discovery.